# Cookies do not seem to do anything

Tags: php, html, cookies

I am fairly new to php (only started today), and i have a problem already. I'm using this html form:

```
<form method="post" name="form" >
     Vorname: <input type="text" name="vorname" /><br />
     Nachname: <input type="text" name="nachname" /><br />
     <input type="button" value="Anmelden" onclick="check(this.form)" />
</form>
```

After the form is submitted, i want to save the inputs as cookies on the next page. It uses this php script:

```
<?php
$timestamp = time();
$vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
$nachname = $_POST['nachname'];
$datum = date("d.m.Y",$timestamp);
$uhrzeit = date("H:i",$timestamp);

setcookie("vor", $vorname, time()+30);
setcookie("nach", $nachname, time()+30);
setcookie("datum", $datum, time()+30);
setcookie('uhrzeit', $uhrzeit, time()+30);
?>
```

So now, when i go back to the previous page, if there are cookies present, it should redirect to a different page using this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['vor'])) {
    header ("Location: Welcome.php");
}
?>
```

However, it does not redirect, i'm not even sure, if the cookies were set at all.
I'm sorry if this is a bit confusing, but i don't know how else to put it. So, if you have any idea where my mistake is, please let me know.

Edit: Turns out i merely forgot to save the file in the proper directory after adding the php script. Embarrassing...

Comment: All decent browsers have tools to inspect cookies (or HTTP headers, which are the way they're sent back to the server). What's yours?

Comment: You testing on localhost, or on a server with an actual qualified domain?

Comment: @Saeven I am currently testing on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're setting the domain for the cookie, it's a parameter that will save you headaches

```
setcookie('cookieName', 'value', time()+30, '/', '.mydomain.com');
```

This will allow you to set the cookie path and will set it for the entire domain/server.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably tricked by [setcookie() default parameters](http://php.net/setcookie), particularly `$path`:

> `bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [,
>   string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool
>   $httponly = false ]]]]]] )`
>
> **path**
>
> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain.
>   If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/
>   directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. **The
>   default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set
>   in.**